# Delphi 6: Opción View>Toggle Form/Unit desactivada

Tags: delphi

Buenas,

Estoy empezando con Delphi y en la creación de un formulario llega un punto en el que se desactiva la opción de la tecla F12.

Si vuelvo a crear de nuevo los formularios (.pas) funciona perfecto, cierro y vuelvo a abrir y ya no funciona.

He leído por ahí (https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27069897/Forms-Disappeared-from-Delphi-IDE.html) que tengo que volver a añadir los componentes que no venían por defecto con Delphi, pero no tengo ni idea de qué componentes son éstos ya que el proyecto lo heredé de otro desarrollador.

Alguna idea?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Trabajo hace 20 años con Delphi y no logro recordar alguna vez en que la tecla F12 haya dejado de funcionar. Claro está que, si tengo abierta una unidad (.pas) que no tiene asociado un archivo .dfm, la tecla F12 no funcionará, pero es que no tiene nada que hacer en ese caso. OJO, que la asociación con el .dfm se puede echar a perder si borras la línea $R que delphi añade automáticamente a tus formularios/módulos de datos.

Comment: ¿En serio hablas de Delphi 6, ahora, en el 2017?. Vamos por Delphi 10.2 (Tokio), que en la anterior cuenta sería el equivalente a Delphi 25. Dale una mirada a las [versiones del compilador](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Compiler_Versions)

Comment: @jachguate Desgraciadamente hay bastantes empresas por aquí que aun trabajan con verisones antiguas de Delphi (6 y 7 sobretodo) debido en gran medida, a que en su día utilizaron de forma indiscriminada paquetes de componentes para los proyectos y ahora no tienen forma de migrarlos porque han quedado obsoletos o descontinuados.

Comment: @Germán, entiendo la situación, en cierta medida ha pasado en todos lados, creo que parte de la _actitud_ de la persona dentro de la industria es buscar la manera de ir hacia adelante y no quedarse estancado, ni en productos ni en conocimiento, en el pasado. Esto porque al final, las empresas dependen cada vez más de los sistemas y, en lo personal, considero que es un riesgo más grande quedarse tan lejos del soporte.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando agregas solo un archivo PAS sin formulario no cuentas con F12 ya que solo es un UNIT o unidad de fuente.

Por otro lado deja atrás a esa versión de delphi es muy antigua y no acepta unicode para las nuevas programaciones. Si deseas programas en antigüedades mejor migra a delphi 2007 pero como te comentan los compañeros mejor un DELPHI XE.

tengo algunos proyectos de clientes que trabajan todavia en delphi6 y tiene una serie de fallas, pero poco apoco los hemos migrado a nuevas generaciones del lenguaje

Comment: Si habla de que "añade" componentes, es que obligatoriamente lo ha creado inicialmente como formulario y no como unit.

Answer (score 0):

No comentas si al abrir de nuevo el formulario (cuando pierdes el F12) te da algún error. **Cosa importante!**
Lo más parecido a la situación que comentas es, que algún paquete de componentes externos no se instale correctamente, o que te falten algunos path de búsqueda en las opciones el entorno.

Parece que el problema es que al abrir de nuevo el formulario, no encuentra alguno de los componentes que hay en él (-concretamente lo que hay en el DFM- y que debería encontrar) y por eso sólo te da acceso al código. 
Pero vuelvo a comentar que al realizar eso te debería dar algún mensaje de error, justo indicando el componente/paquete problemático.

Algo similar a esto, pero con alguno de los componentes que tiene tu formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cuanto a añadir componentes que antes estaban instalados y que ahora no tienes, justo ese mensaje de error y el código (tanto del PAS como del DFM) te dará información de los componentes. 
Dabajo de la definción del formulario (class), tienes los componentes que contiene y la clase de cada uno de ellos. Por ejemplo:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    cxGrid1DBTableView1: TcxGridDBTableView;
    cxGrid1Level1: TcxGridLevel;
    cxGrid1: TcxGrid;
    JvBitBtn1: TJvBitBtn;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
```

La clase de cada elemento (TEdit, TcxGrid, TJvBitBtn,...) te está dando pistas de qué componente es y el paquete al que pertenece.
Pon aquí esa lista de componentes y te podremos ayudar a encontrar los paquetes que debes tener instalados para trabajar con ese proyecto.